# Multi dimensional python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a multi dimensional dictionary in python so that I can access them using the following notation:

```
test['SYSTEM']['home']['GET']
test['SYSTEM']['home']['POST']
```

What would be the easiest way to set these values, in other languages I can do this:

```
test['SYSTEM']['home']['GET'] = True
test['SYSTEM']['home']['POST'] = False
```

Comment: Have you tried doing that in Python?

Comment: Exactly similar in python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a recursive [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) based structure, like this

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> nesteddict = lambda: defaultdict(nesteddict)
>>>
>>> test = nesteddict()
>>> test['SYSTEM']['home']['GET'] = True
>>> test['SYSTEM']['home']['POST'] = False
>>>
>>> test['SYSTEM']['home']['GET']
True
>>> test['SYSTEM']['home']['POST']
False
```

Whenever you access a key in `test`, which is not there in it, it will invoke the function passed to `nesteddict`'s argument to create a value for the key.

Comment: More details on Autovivification here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple dictionary, you could also use tuples as keys:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[('SYSTEM', 'home', 'GET')] = True
```

this might or might not be useful in your case.